# How can I share state data between components using custom hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following custom hook called `useFlash`:

```
import { useState } from 'react';


export default function useFlash() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const showFlash = (message: string) => {
    setMessages([...messages, message]);
  };

  const clearMessage = (index: number) => {
    setMessages(messages.filter((_m, i) => index !== i));
  };

  return {
    messages,
    showFlash,
    clearMessage
  };
}
```

Then I have this HOC providing it to two other components:

```
import React from 'react';
import useFlash from '../effects/useFlash';

const withFlash = (WrappedComponent: React.Component) => {
  const WithFlash = () => {
    const { messages, showFlash, clearMessage } = useFlash();

    return (
      <WrappedComponent
        messages={messages}
        showFlash={showFlash}
        clearFlashMessage={clearMessage}
      />
    );
  };

  return WithFlash;
};

export default withFlash;
```

It works well, except each use of the HOC gets its own state data. I need the state to be global. I know I can use contexts with consumer/providers, but I thought this way would be a little simpler. It is not proving to be true, is there a way to make this global?

Comment: This wont work among two different functions. each time you import the state, it will be setted with the initial value. The solution is to use the "context" hook

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll need to use Context, but it's not that bad..

create your context..

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const FlashContext = React.createContext();

export const FlashProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  return (
    <FlashContext.Provider value={{ messages, setMessages }}>
      {children}
    </FlashContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

wrap your components in the provider somewhere higher in the tree..

```
import React from "react";
import { FlashProvider } from "./flash-context";

const App = () => <FlashProvider><TheRest /></FlashProvider>;

export default App;
```

then use the context in your custom hook..

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { FlashContext } from "./flash-context";

export default function useFlash() {
  const { messages, setMessages } = useContext(FlashContext);

  const showFlash = (message) => {
    setMessages([...messages, message]);
  };

  const clearMessage = (index) => {
    setMessages(messages.filter((_m, i) => index !== i));
  };

  return {
    messages,
    showFlash,
    clearMessage
  };
}
```

Comment: I forgot about the new useContext hook. I also didn’t think about putting the Provider in the context file. This helps a lot, thanks! I mostly wanted to avoid having to redundantly wrap my consuming components in Consumers. This does that perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome. I learned something new today. Thanks @lecstor