# Custom hook state update not re-rendering the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I wrote a custom hook to set and retrieve the cookie in the browser.

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    
    import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
    
    const useCookie = (key, _options = {}) => {
      const cookies = new Cookies();
      const [item, setItemValue] = useState(() => {
        if (cookies.get(key)) {
          console.log(cookies.get(key));
    
          return cookies.get(key);
        }
    
        return 0;
      });
    
      const setValue = (value, options) => {
        setItemValue(value);
        cookies.set(key, value, options);
      };
    
      const removeItem = () => {
        cookies.remove(key);
      };
      return [item, setValue, removeItem];
    };
    
    export default useCookie;
```

My concern is I am using a hook in one my components to set the value of cookie for instance like mentioned below.

```
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useCookie('count')
  const handleCartCount = () => {
    setCartCount((parseInt(cartCount, 10) + 1).toString());
  };
```

so far so good, I can see the browser dev tools that the value of cookie count is incremented whenever I am calling `handleCartCount` the problem I am facing is in the same page I have cart Icon in the header component and I am using the same cookie hook to retrieve the value of cookie in that component like this.

```
const [basketCount] = useCookie('count')
```

but unfortunately I can't see the updated value instantly I have to refresh the page to see the updated value.

I suspect I am missing some basics with custom hooks here or how state update happens?

Here is the sandbox to reflect this behaviour https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-swirles-9cjbqg?file=/src/App.js, please open the sandbox in new window to debug. (https://9cjbqg.csb.app/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I share state data between components using custom hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979668/how-can-i-share-state-data-between-components-using-custom-hooks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause in the hook, they don't know when you are changing the values in browser cookies (in other hook). Found `Cookies` have `addChangeListener / removeChangeListener` can listen to changes too but you are create new instance in start of hook so it can't notify to other instance hook.

To solve this you can create `Cookies` in parent or some where can access instance of `Cookies` by your hook.

In this example, i create an singleton class to hold instance of `Cookies` and get it instead of create new, using listener to listen to changes and it work.

*hook.ts*

```js
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

class SingletonCookies {
  private static _instance: SingletonCookies | null = null;
  static instance: SingletonCookies = this._instance ?? new SingletonCookies();
  cookies: Cookies;
  constructor() {
    this.cookies = new Cookies();
    SingletonCookies._instance ??= this;
  }
}

const useCookie = <T = any>(key: string, defaultValue: T): [T, (value: T) => void] => {
  const cookies = SingletonCookies.instance.cookies;
  const [ivalue, _setValue] = useState<T>(defaultValue);

  const setValue = (value: T) => {
    _setValue(value);
    cookies.set(key, value);
  };

  const listener = () => {
    console.log("cookie changes");
    const currentValue: T = (cookies.get(key) as T) ?? defaultValue;
    if (currentValue !== ivalue) _setValue(currentValue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    cookies.addChangeListener(listener);
    return () => cookies.removeChangeListener(listener);
  });

  return [ivalue, setValue];
};

export default useCookie;
```

*component*

```js
import useCookie from "./use_cookie";

export const TodoCouter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useCookie<number>("todo_count", 0);
  const cName = "TodoCouter";
  return (
    <div>
      counter: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoCouter;
```

*parent component*

```js
...
<TodoCouter />
-
<TodoCouter />
...
```

[image]

Comment: Please help me in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74017672/component-not-getting-rendered-on-updating-state-in-custom-hook